# How can I run background worker process in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

As per title, how can I run background worker process in Google Cloud like [Heroku worker dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#scaling-a-process-type)?

I read the Google Cloud documentation and the articles seem to assume I always want to deploy a web application. I don't want a web application at all. And then there are other documentation on Cloud Pub/Sub, Task Queues, Cloud Tasks, Cloud Functions, Cron etc. which seems to be just different types of event triggered one-off routines.

What I want is just a worker process that does stuff and update the database, and can gracefully shutdown when requested like [SIGTERM](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#graceful-shutdown-with-sigterm) in Heroku.

Comment: It sounds like a `Cron` job to me. create a vm that runs cron jobs to update your database. Is that what you want?

Comment: What does the worker process "do"?  How does it know when to do work?  This appears to be a core tenet in the different compute options provided by GCP.  If time based then Cloud Scheduler.  If Web request then Cloud Functions, App Engine or Compute Engine.  If always running bare metal OS then Compute Engine or Kubernetes Engine.  Next comes concept of scaling ... one worker or multiple as a function of demand?

Comment: @Kolban the worker process can do anything other than a web server process. For example, a terminal service process that listens for clients for indefinite amount of time and take commands, a background process to crawl the internet, a background process with socket connections to get latest crypto prices and update a database in near real time. Let me check Compute Engine or Kubernetes Engine for time being. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: A container on **Google Kubernetes Engine**.

All your mentioned GCP solutions requires triggering, either from HTTP-requests, events, tasks or time, in order to run your code.

If you just want to have a job running in the background, you can create a container that runs a single never-ending process (e.g. java, node, etc) and deploy it to GKE (check out *DaemonSet* and *StatefulSet*)

Alternative solution: **Google Compute Engine**.